# SQL queries using UNION

Tags: sql-update, union

I'm new to writing larger queries checking multiple tables. I have this `SELECT` query which works well:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM companies WHERE email='$email' UNION SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
```

However, I am doing an edit page using this `UPDATE` query which does not work:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE companies SET name='$name',address='$address',city='$city',state='$state',zip='$zip' WHERE email='$email' UNION UPDATE users SET name='$name',address='$address',city='$city',state='$state',zip='$zip' WHERE email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't union update statements together. You simply have to split it into to separate commands. Or in other words, run two queries, one for companies and one for users.

Comment: Thanks...didn't know that. Currently I have `$email = $_SESSION['email']` so the query updates the tables where it finds the email. So I would have to first do an if select query then update for both tables?

Answer (score 0):

according to your question you can update with two update

```
$sql1="UPDATE companies SET name='$name',address='$address',city='$city',state='$state',zip='$zip' WHERE email='$email'";
$sql2="UPDATE users SET name='$name',address='$address',city='$city',state='$state',zip='$zip' WHERE email='$email";
```

OR

you can select and find the table in which $email is present.

```
sql1="select name form user where email=$email "
sql2="select name form companies where email=$email "
if(count($sql1>0)){
UPDATE user SET name='$name',address='$address',city='$city',state='$state',zip='$zip' WHERE email='$email'
}
if(count($sql2>0)){
UPDATE companies SET name='$name',address='$address',city='$city',state='$state',zip='$zip' WHERE email='$email'
}
```